# I don't understand these assembly code and machine code differences if assembly code instructions are equivalent of machine code instructions

Tags: assembly, executable

Some people say that assembly language = machine language, just that we use mnemonics in assembly language.

After reading Petzold's "CODE", I can't still understand how some of the assembly codes are translated into machine code.

For example (from Tutorials Point's Assembly Course):

```
_start:             ;tells linker entry point
   mov  edx,len     ;message length
   mov  ecx,msg     ;message to write

section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;our dear string
```

What I understand is that msg contains "Hello, world!" and it's moved into ECX.

But as I know, in x86 the ECX can just store 32 bits.

Then how can we move "Hello, world!" - which is more than 32 bits - into ECX?

And what is the equivalence of that part

```
section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;our dear string
```

in machine code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a good one. It gets at the fundamental computer concept of *indirection.*

The normal way for a computer to treat a string of text like "Hello, world!" is to keep it in memory as a series of characters. For example:

```
Memory address    Memory contents
8201              'H'
8202              'e'
8203              'l'
8204              'l'
8205              'o'
8206              ','
8207              ' '
...               ...
820E              0
```

The value of `msg` in this example is 0x8201. It is not `'H'`. Therefore, the value 0x8201 is moved to register `ecx`.

Later, anyone who wants the message can read the 0x8201 out of `ecx`, then go to memory address 0x8201 to find the start of the actual text message. Does this make sense?

Comment: But how is this assembly code translated into machine code. `section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa` . I mean what is its "machine code" version?

Comment: Yes, I see your question. Its answer is subtle, not easily grasped. The memory model takes some getting used to. The `section .data` does not itself generate machine code, but rather configures the assembler for further use by you. The `db 'Hello, world!', 0xa` just makes the string of bytes I have depicted above. You have not told the assembler where in memory to put this string, so it chooses a place such as at address 0x8201. The symbol `msg` then represents the address (which is just a number) 0x8201. It's all symbolic, and it takes some thinking about. Good luck.

Comment: Got it. So not everything written in assembly code has a directly equvalence in machine code.

Answer (score 2):

With `msg db` you define address containing the string sequence of bytes. With `mov ecx, msg` you load just this address not its content. Then it's possible to load string by loading [ecx], [ecx+1] etc.

.data defines program section. .text usually contains machine code, .data modifiable program code. There can be more of them such as exception handling labels etc.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax depends on the assembler, for MASM or ML (Microsoft's version of MASM), the syntax would be

```
        mov     ecx,offset msg    ;ecx = offset (address) of msg
```

which makes it clear that the offset or address of msg is being loaded into ecx, as opposed to the first 4 bytes of msg.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the command

```
mov ecx,msg
```

does not actually move the whole string `Hello, world!` to the register, but rather a pointer to its beginning. The assembler directive

```
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa
```

apparently defines a memory location which contains the actual string `Hello, world!` and can be referenced by the label `msg`. However, actual usage is a bit hard to tell, as further usage of the contents of the register is missing.

Comment: That assembly code assumes that the "Hello world" string is already in memory? And the strimg starts from 0xa? But how is this assembly code translated into machine code. `section .data msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa` . I mean what is its "machine code" version?

Comment: To my understanding, the string is not actually converted to machine code. The assembler apparently generates some binary file which includes both the translated code and some raw data which is also included in the binary and can be defined in the file that is assembled.

Answer (score 0):

For x86, Intel's insn reference manual lists all the encodings for every instruction (see the links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

`mov  ecx, msg` is the `mov r32, imm32` encoding.  The address of `msg` is eventually filled in into those 4 bytes in the instruction at link time, because that's when the final absolute address is determined.

`mov ecx, [msg]` would be a 4-byte load from an absolute address (the start of msg).  It would be encoded as `mov r32, r/m32`, using a memory-operand encoding for the source.

`len` is probably defined with and `equ` assembler directive.  So it's a *symbol*, but its value isn't an address.  Instead, its value is a number in the asm source file.  `msg` is a symbol, and also a label, whose value *is* an address.